# Verify SP2 Install for MOSS?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have 12.0.0.6421 showing in Central Admin, which would seem to indicate that SP2 was installed. However, when I run an STSADM command to backup a site collection, I do not see the message informing me that it's "setting the site collection to be-read only for the duration of the backup" as described here:

http://bobfox.securespsite.com/FoxBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=121

I simply get the "Operation completed successfully" message I used to get pre-SP2.  Does this mean that SP2 wasn't installed correctly?

Comment: Please leave SP2 tag in place.

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate [dangling version tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62545/please-help-me-eliminate-year-tags-and-dangling-version-numbers). SP2 as a tag is useless, because it's not a product (as far as I know, it's something-sp2). Please retag accordingly (Moss-SP2, Sparepoint-SP2, Windows-XP-SP2, whatever seems appropriate).

Comment: Many enterprises use MOSS (2007) and have different SP levels for different reasons. SP2 tag is there for a specific reason. Also, if someone using tags in combination to filter a search then this makes sense?

Comment: I'm not disputing the fact that Moss is widely used. It's simply that SP2 on its own refers to a version, much like `2.0` or `2003` would. It is my understanding that tags are searchable items for technologies or concepts. If users search for Windows-XP-SP2, it's not the same as searching for Moss2007-SP2. Likewise, tags become fields of expertise, and have experts and wiki pages. One can be an expert on `c++`, `moss`, `moss2007`, but hardly on `2.0` or `SP2`.

Comment: I'm no tag overlord, just a guy trying to sort things out and keep things manageable and easy to browse. If you feel I am in error or out of my league, you sir are in your right to wish me a prompt visit to hell. It's just that there's so much haphazard tagging going on that I've started a [cleanup effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62545/please-help-me-eliminate-year-tags-and-dangling-version-numbers) to correct the issue. With the `SP2` tag remaining here, it remains available to new users to use and spread again.

Comment: If I'm having an issue with the MOSS SP2 service pack and I search here under "MOSS", this question/answer comes back in position #99. If I search for using "MOSS SP2" (without the quotes), it comes in position #1. I'm not trying to be awkward but this would seem to be self explanatory. The priority is to help others who are having a similar problem, and not get hung up on the semantics of tagging per say.

Comment: Isn't the hit made on the title?

Comment: Good point... in that case we can remove the tag.

Comment: I think this way we will be able to find it still. Thank you very much! I'm in your debt.

Comment: Not at all; we were talking about two different things :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anthony,

Showing a build of 6421 does indeed indicate that SP2 is in-place.  Just to make sure, I checked my own farm and VMs as well as a reliable external source (an entry from Todd Klindt's blog: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=154).  I didn't doubt the build number, but it never hurts to confirm  :-)

At first, I thought I understood where the issue might be, so I ran some tests.  First, I ran an STSADM backup in *catastrophic mode* to backup my entire farm.  Since this isn't a site collection backup, no locking should occur:

```
stsadm -o backup -directory \\ss-nas3\backups\test -backupmethod full
```

My catastrophic backup ran without issue, and I didn't receive any message about a lock or read-only behavior.  I looked at my ULS logs, as well, and confirmed that no lock was being established (searching for "sitelock" and "lock").  This was as I expected, as I was doing a catastrophic backup -- not a site collection backup.

Next, I tried a site collection backup:

```
stsadm -o backup -url https://www.sculpted-system.com/pictures -filename \\ss-nas3\backups\test\SiteCollectionBackupTest.bak
```

Strangely enough, I didn't see a locking message here, either.  I took a look at the ULS logs, and I saw nothing to indicate that a lock was put in place.  Finally, I performed an

> stsadm -o getsitelock ...

... while the backup was running and was greeted with this:

```
<SiteLock Lock="none" />
```

ARGH!  That's *not* what I wanted (or expected) to see!  Clearly, there was a problem ... so, I tried coming at it from a different angle.  I took a look at the MSDN documentation for the STSADM -o backup command, and it clearly indicated that a lock should occur by default.  It also indicated that the **-nositelock** switch should work to override the behavior.  So, I tried adding -nositelock to my site collection backup command line.

Guess what: it choked on **-nositelock** with a command line error (invalid parameter).

Doing an **STSADM -help backup** indicated that **-nositelock** was *not* a valid switch for my environment.  None of the new switches I expected (e.g., **-nositelock** and **-force**) were present.  It's as if my production farm was stuck in pre-SP2 with regard to backups.

I decided to check a development VM I had that was also build 6421 (but different image -- amongst other things, Win2K8 instead of Win2K3 R2), I saw that the **-nositelock** *was* a valid command line option.  So I checked another development VM that was also build 6421 (but Win2K3 R2 like my "regular farm").  **-nositelock** was a valid option there, too.

I had applied SP2 the same across all three environments when upgrading (WSSv3 SP2 bits, following by MOSS 2007 SP2 bits, followed by a run of the configuration wizard), so I wasn't sure what was going on.

For fun, I ran a site collection backup on each of the VMs that correctly displayed that **-nositelock** was a valid command line switch for site collection backups, and I was met with the locking message I didn't see earlier (and that you weren't seeing, either).  Clearly, the SP2 updates were operating as I expected them to everywhere except my primary (production) farm.

I concluded I must have somehow done something wrong as part of upgrading my farm, so I tried re-running the WSSv3 SP2 update (first) and MOSS 2007 SP2 update (second) on each box.  With each update on each box, I was told the that the update had already been applied.  So, I dropped back and punted: I re-ran the configuration wizard to see if it would do anything.  I then rebooted the two (virtual) boxes in the farm.

No change.

At this point, I can only confirm that you aren't losing your mind.  Two of my all-in-one development VMs with SP2 build 6421 operate as expected, but my two-server/VM farm that is build 6421 that *should* be locking on site collection backup is not.

I think I'll probably follow up with a friend who is a Microsoft TAM.  If I learn anything, I'll post it here and probably on my blog.  In the meantime, you might want to follow up with Microsoft, as well.  Clearly, something isn't working as expected.

For what it's worth!

Comment: Bouncing some Twitter messages back and forth with Todd Klindt, he indicated checking the version info on STSADM.exe.  Checking my "bad" farm, I had a version of 6418.1000.  My working VMs had versions of 6421.1000 (expected) and 6500.5000 (weird, but that's a different story ...).  Anyway, check your STSADM.exe version.  Right now, prevailing hypothesis is some form of botched install or laydown of files.  No word on fixing it, but I'll probably start working that tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the input Sean, glad to know I wasn't imagining things! I'm going to be re-building this server and (w2K8 on VMWare VM) am waiting to see if the same thing happens again - I will also post any findings here :-)

Comment: I have submitted a report to Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=484498&SiteID=428

I can also confirm that my development, staging and production VMs (all with SP2) are all showing STSADM version 12.0.6418.1000. Oddly, I can see the preupgrade command when I issue the help switch?

Comment: Interesting, Anthony!  Your finding highlights my primary concern with trying something like simply overwriting STSADM.exe.  Such an overwrite addresses the executable, but not any backing dependencies (SP assemblies) that may also be of the wrong version.  The fact that you can see *some* SP2-related commands/switches but not others tells me that the issue goes deeper.  Our TAM here has been out, so I haven't been able to run the issue by him yet ... but I'm glad to hear that you were able to supply feedback via Connect.  I'll continue to post anything I find/learn!

Comment: I just performed a full crawl on the destination server to which I had moved the content DB and got the following error in the crawl log:

A runtime exception was detected. Details follow. 
Message: A duplicate site ID dc238e9b-41d0-4a1b-b3db-9eb03daf9e77(http://destinationserver) was found. This might be caused by restoring a content database from one server farm into a different server farm without first removing the original database and then running stsadm -o preparetomove. 

Looks like profiles are out of synch indicating that SP2 is not doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: It certainly sounds like STSADM.exe isn't the only file that didn't get updated ...

Comment: Gonna attempt to re-install SP2 on spare server, wonder if that would work? Failing that, going to call Microsoft... I could re-build the servers and if I got the correct build number next time, just cross my fingers. But I honestly wouldn't rest easy doing it like that...

Comment: Update: didn't re-apply SP2. Worked with MSDN Support to re-synch the databases and installed June Updates. Everything worked fine after that. Here are the steps:
Stsadm –o sync –listolddatabases 30 , if you see any old guid’s then run below command

Stsadm –o sync –deleteolddatabases  0

Stsadm –o execsvcadmjobs.

Installing the June Updates seemed to fix everything, but I am still not satisfied as to the original cause of the problem. Feeling a blog post coming on! :-)

Comment: So, the June CU's took care of updating all of the associated binaries without issue?  Regardless, glad to hear that things are back in working order for you.  I'll be doing a farm rebuild soon (trying to get infrastructure ready for 2010), so I'm going to sit tight until then.  Thanks for sharing your findings, Anthony!

Comment: No prob. Note that it was normal to have a different build number for the STSADM compared to the SharePoint install version. At least that's what he said :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of SharePoint Versions maintained by the SharePoint community here:
http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/SharePointAdministrationWiki/SharePoint+Versions

Answer (score 0):

Your version is correct for SP2; I wouldn't worry about the STSADM message appearing; it's a pretty inconsistent tool.